# Why does Ninject Mvc NinjectHttpApplication not use IControllerFactory for CreateControllerFactory()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I was looking over the Ninject MVC source code, and the method that generates a controller factory for overwriting the default is hardcoded to only return a NinjectControllerFactory, however as its set as virtual it would make more sense (in my eyes) to use an IControllerFactory.

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates the controller factory that is used to create the controllers.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The created controller factory.</returns>
protected virtual NinjectControllerFactory CreateControllerFactory()
{
    return new NinjectControllerFactory(this.Kernel);
}
```

I love Ninject and I am sure there is a reason why it was done this way, but have a problem at the moment where I need to write my own ControllerFactory and use that, but would rather still use the NinjectHttpApplication. I know I could just inherit from NinjectControllerFactory and then override the method to return this new instance, but I would not be using any functionality from the Ninject flavour so it just seems that it would be a bit of a smell...

So is there a reason why it doesn't use IController or is this something that may be changed in the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are refering either to MVC 1.0 or 2.0. MVC 3.0 takes a completely different way.

No there is no reason for not returning an `IControllerFactory`. This was most likely just an automatic refactoring and was not recognized. On the other hand if you are not using the `NinjectControllerFactory` there is almost no reason to use the extension at all.

Comment: Thats odd, the source code I got for the latest build against Ninject V 2.2.0.0 still uses ControllerFactory. Unless I was an idiot and got the MVC2 version ones. Thought it was odd that you were not using a DependencyResolver. Checked source in git and realised it is not a problem now.